# PowerApps multiple cascading dropdowns from SharePoint List Choices Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula

I have a relatively simple scenario which I am trying to implement in PowerApps, but can't seem to make it work.

I have **2 dropdowns** which source values will be from a **SharePoint list** with 2 columns **Region**  and **Department**. Both these columns are ***Choice*** type columns

[image]

**Department** dropdown will depend on **Region** selected

1. Region dropdown *Items* property

   `Choices([@MySharePointList].Region)`
2. Department dropdown *Items* property

   `Filter([@MySharePointList], Region.Value = ddlRegion.Selected.Value).Department`

I think it filters correctly, however they are *Records*. As a result, the dropdown has items but are shown as empty items.

How do I retrieve the actual value of the **Department** for this dropdown?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @thebernardlim, does my below answer works for you?

Answer (score 0):

When Power Apps retrieves values from Choice columns, they are returned as records like this: `{ Value: "Warehouse" }` So my guess is that you're only missing '.Value' from the end of your formula.

Comment: Yes that's how I understood too, however there is no value returned for ".Value". It is even marked red and Power Apps doesn't recognize such a property.

Comment: Managed to find the answer in another thread https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/307470/power-apps-multiple-cascading-drop-downs-from-sharepoint-list-choices-column

Answer (score 0):

**Department** column *Items* Formula:

`Distinct(Filter([@MySharePointList], Region.Value = ddlRegion.Selected.Value), Department.Value)`

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula for Department drop down **Items** property:

```
Distinct(Filter([@MySharePointList], Region.Value = ddlRegion.Selected.Value), Department.Value)
```

**SharePoint list**:

[image]

**Power Apps output**:

[image]